# How to stop my script continuously issuing emails?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

```
function reminder() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  var d = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var recipients = data[i].slice(3, 6).filter(String).join(",");
    if (recipients == "") continue;
    if (data[i][6] <= new Date(d + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) && data[i][6] >= new Date(d + 5 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) && data[i][7] == '') {
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: recipients,
        subject: 'Reminder Process Update Required in 1 week',
        htmlBody: 'Hello ' + data[i][2] + ', the  process page for <b>' + data[i][1] + '</b> is due for review in 1 week. Please review the content and contact the Process team before its due date if amendments are required.'
      });
      sh.getRange(i + 1, 9).setValue('sent');
    }
    else if (data[i][6] <= new Date(d + 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) && data[i][6] >= new Date(d + 28 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) && data[i][7] == '') {
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: recipients,
        subject: 'Reminder Process Update Required in 1 month',
        htmlBody: 'Hello ' + data[i][2] + ', the process page for <b>' + data[i][1] + '</b> is due for review in review in 1 month. Please review the content and contact the Process Mapping team before its due date if amendments are required.'
      });
      sh.getRange(i + 1, 8).setValue('sent');
    }
  }
}
```

Currently Im facing this issue 1), If the due date is 1 week on the table the script will continuously issue the email and apply "sent" onto the table though still send the emails, 2). If the due date is 1 month then it will issue the email however once "sent" is inputted into the sheet no further emails will be issued which is fine until this causes an issue when the date becomes to 1 week before then it will not issue the second reminder email advising its due

Comment: In summary it should work as follows: 1 month before issue email then do not issue any emails until 1 week. 1 email should be issued in each 1 month and 1 week and it should not continuously issue emails. Apologies im not sure how to resolve this -heres a link to the sheet with the script - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Qw8WefbVkS-AQXi1CcZ0z2CL-P0oNSZYqeT40oVF6go/edit#gid=0

Comment: Have you tried to use last_sent date field to control it? And run the method daily?

Comment: Hey sorry im a complete novice at this so not sure how to incorporate this however Im getting 2 issues firstly under the week parameter it continuously issues emails when the script is set to run every minute though should stop after the word "sent" is added onto the sheet. However when its 1 month it only issues email once then does not let any other emails to be issued even though a further email should be issued again when it comes to 1 week